# Different images for left bar?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, column

**I have four categories and each category has individual CMS page, and each individual page has left bar with image**. Where in another Category CMS page of another image. So this continuous till four categories. So how to achieve this by call up media or should I create each template page to do this.

Can anyone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you add screenshots? Also, add that `left bar` code (phtml code).

Comment: so what you  want you want to remove the sidebar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more complex the Magento product, the more you will have to edit each and every category and make them unique.

- Duplicate your existing `list.phtml` file. Actually make five copies,
  just to have one unedited backup(since you have four categories).

> app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

- Change the name of the file to anything you want, but honestly just
  add an underscore and a quick name of the category

> list_thisCategory.phtml

- Add the following code to the category’s “`Custom Design`” Tab /
  “`Custom Layout Update`” section:

> ```
> <reference name="product_list">
>        <action method="setTemplate">
>           <template>catalog/product/list_thisCategory.phtml</template>
>        </action>
>      </reference>
> ```

- Now open up your thisCategory.phtml file and begin editing it.
- Any changes you make to that file will only effect the one category.

  Attaching a screen shot

[image]